# Magento admin panel "system" menu option disappeared from my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, magento, operating-system

Magento admin panel "system" menu option disappeared from my website.
I just rolled back an extension installation, but I'm unable to get "system" menu in my admin panel.

Comment: which extension you have used?

Answer (score 0):

```
It all happens because of the bad permissions to your JS folder.

Just CHMOD the js folder to 755 and js/index.php to 644 .

Also make sure, all of your js files in that folder are with 644 permission.
If none of the above thing works, then do one thing!
Just delete the existing JS folder or rename it to something different.
And then reupload the JS folder from default Magento package.
```